# How to add Rich Text Editor input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add text area input as shown in image. I do not want to write extra code for this. Is there any library for this?

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Comment: @AjeetShah any free one

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg, this one is really nice, I personally used for my project

Comment: [Standalone Editors Built on Draft.js](https://github.com/nikgraf/awesome-draft-js#standalone-editors-built-on-draftjs)

Answer (score 0):

The most popular one that I know is [TinyMCE](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce). They have some paid versions if you want more features.

If you don't need something that advanced you could opt for something like [Summer note](https://summernote.org) or [Quill](https://quilljs.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try Froala. It's a rich text editor that you can integrate with React as well as other frameworks. You can read more [here](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/react/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34026754)